# Get controller properties in HTML, is everything meant to go in a viewbag?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

From what I read in various tutorials, or simply the sample project, the Controller use the ViewBag to store anything that will be dipsplayed on the page.

In the Controller I can just type `ViewBag.AnythingIWant = "Foo";`, and it'll render in the HTML. Apparently that's what is done in the sample project, at least for title and various texts.

But most of the text is hardcoded in the HTML and obviously I don't want that. Considering I'm not new to C# or MVC in Xamarin (mobile development), I feel like I should grasp this pretty quick, but I don't. Could someone clarify to me the following :

My `Controller` knows the `ViewModel` (which does most of the work) and himself uses the `Model` privately. I'm used (from iOS dev) for the controller to be the last layer of UI, and inside the controller I would just have all my labels and whatever I want, and I can fill them with whatever is available in the ViewModel.

Here, there is this HTML layer that I don't know how to connect to the controller.

I have a **strong** feeling that putting everything in the ViewBag cannot be the way to go. Could anyone briefly reveal the piece I am missing to use proper objects inside the HTML ?

Razor might be what's confusing me, considering whatever I add publicly in my Controller, I can't find it in the related HTML using `@MyProperty`

I know this is pretty broad question but I know that I only miss a small piece of knowledge to unlock everything.

Comment: Just pass the view model to the view, as expected in asp.net mvc. https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3

Comment: If you have a view model (which you should), then you should never need to use `ViewBag`.

Comment: You can pass a model object when returning a `View` result, this would be a model used by view to render HTML

Comment: yes, put all your staff in viewmodel. ViewModel should be simple class with some logic related to UI. No business logic. Like @Model.PageTitle.

Comment: Oh alright. You can add parameters to the view(); Damn that should change everything. Let me have a quick try at this

Comment: Yep, that was actually that simple. I wondered why using the @model on top returned null, now I know ! Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, pass a ViewModel to the View to be rendered!

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel { Name = "some string" };
    return View("Index", viewModel);
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model MyViewModel @* Tell Razor which ViewModel to expect *@
@{ string name = Model.Name; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Like I said to the others, I didn't know you were supposed to pass the viewmodel as a parameter when returning the view. It all makes sense now!